# A question about connections on Riemann Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I have been self studying calculus on line bundles on Riemann Surfaces from “Riemann Surfaces by Way of Complex Analytic Geometry” Chapter 6 by Dror Varolin. I am trying to understand why the connection form is not globally defined. In the book, it says it follows from the equation for two connection forms $\omega$ and $\omega’$ coming from two different frames on an open set, we have
$$
\omega=\omega’+\frac{df}{f}
$$
I don’t understand why this implies $w$ cannot be defined globally. We already know $f$ cannot have a zero for it is the “ratio” of two frames. I am somewhat new in the topic so this might be very easy to see. Thanks in advance!

[The part in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4p2Q.jpg)

Comment: The connection forms do not agree on overlap, so you don't have a global connection form. The curvature form, however, is globally defined, since $d\omega = d\omega'$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for the reply! What if I have a single $\omega$ defined on the entire $X$? Then, $f$ is identity and the equation is trivially true.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez oh okay, so if I choose different local frames, I cannot find a global 1 form. Is there anything that prevents me from chosing the frame globally?